# Symfony2 : automatically adding a listener to a dispatcher

Tags: php, symfony, dispatcher, event-listener

I want to listen to a custom event I created :

Here is the event :

```
class UserActivationEvent extends Event
{
    const NAME = 'my_app.user.activation';
}
```

I have an event dispatcher thanks to the following service :

```
event_dispatcher:
    class: Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher
    arguments:
        - "@service_container"
```

I dispatch my event in my code :

```
$dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
$event = new UserActivationEvent();
$dispatcher->dispatch(UserActivationEvent::NAME, $event);
```

I created a listener :

```
class UserActivationListener
{
    public function onUserActivation($event)
    {
        var_dump('I am listening'); exit();
    }
}
```

that i registered as a service :

```
my_app.legacy.listener.user_activation:
    class: Acme\LegacyBundle\EventListener\UserActivationListener
    tags:
        - { name: my_app.event_listener, event: my_app.user.activation }
```

But this code doesn't trigger my listener. I am force to add the following lines in my script :

```
$listener = new UserActivationListener();
$this->dispatcher->addListener(UserActivationEvent::NAME, [$listener, 'onUserActivation']);
```

Then I can see the listener is called.

**My Question :**

Is there a way to add a listener to a dispatcher in the service declaration ?
I don't want my script to be aware of the listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tag of your `EventListener`, set the `method` attribute to `onUserActivation`:

```
my_app.legacy.listener.user_activation:
    class: Acme\LegacyBundle\EventListener\UserActivationListener
    tags:
        - { name: my_app.event_listener, event: my_app.user.activation method: onUserActivation }
```

To make the `EventListener` calling this method when the event is fired.

**EDIT**

You need also to use the tag name `kernel.event_listener`:

```
my_app.legacy.listener.user_activation:
    class: Acme\LegacyBundle\EventListener\UserActivationListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: my_app.user.activation method: onUserActivation }
```

Read [this documentation chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html#connecting-listeners) for more informations
(there is a paragraph called "Registering Event Listeners in the Service Container").

Comment: Yes in fact I was just missing the kernel.event_listener but the method is not mandatory if its named after the event (in my case onMyAppUserActivation).. but I was hoping to use a custom name such as my_app.event_listener instead of kernel.event_listener :(

Comment: Right, I just see that you are naming the method like the event name, so the `method ` is not mandatory. For the listener tag name, it's something that is based on built-in tag names and cannot be custom without a lot of overrides.